# Unexpected rotation of the gun's turret when it arrives at a certain value, How do i can solve that?

Tags: game-engine, game-development, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

***Video shows the problem***

[Click here to watch the problem on YOUTUBE](https://youtu.be/eyJhAPrypJ0)

I am working on a gun turret game.
The turret should rotate based on the rotation of the camera's view, all is done perfectly.
I am using FInterpTo to make the rotation smooth.

***The problem is:***
Unfortunately, unexpected something else has done, When the rotation arrives at 180, the rotation will be reflected.
I tried a lot and a lot to solve this problem but without any results.
If anyone had the same problem, I hope to help me.

***The blueprint of Turret Rotation with FInterp function***

**(Yaw rotation)** variable represents the value of turret rotation
[image]

[image]

Comment: You can try using [RInterp To](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Math/Interpolation/RInterpTo/) instead. Rotations are always limited to be between -180° and 180° and so are the floats representing them. If you use rotations instead, it may solve your problem. I understand that you only want one axis to be interpolated, so you can create two rotators using [Make Rotator](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Math/Rotator/MakeRotator/) and feed your float value into one of the inputs. The resulting rotator should contain the correct value.

Comment: It didn’t occur to me that the problem could be there.
The solution is RInterp to.
Thank you Max Play

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

***Rinterp to*** instead of using ***FInterp to***